# Proper SSH ENV in an Ambari bootstrapped HDP 2.2 Cluster

Tags: shell, hadoop, ssh, ambari

Just rolled out a new 2.2 cluster w/ Ambari, which was awesome, but now when I hit the shell with my user, I don’t have the right JAVA_HOME set in my env.

Is there something I should source on login that will setup my ENV properly (not just JAVA_HOME) or do I manually set the JAVA_HOME to the Ambari install location (/usr/jdk64/java-*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: `/usr/hdp/2.2.4.2-2/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-config.sh`